# TCP segment with flags ACK, PSH, URG

Tags: tcp, firewall

Can a TCP data segment with a 1 byte length have, at the same time, the flags ACK, PSH, URG set ? Is it conform or not to the TCP protocol ?

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not provided enough information to be able to answer the question. Please edit the question to include the firewall model and configuration. Also, remember that programming and host/server questions are off-topic here

Comment: "_When establishing the connection to the database (after the TCP 3-way handshake)_" After the three-way handshake, the connection is already established. I do not know what yo mean about establishing it _after_ the three-way handshake because it is established _during_ the three-way handshake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> During the initial handshake, the OJDBC driver sends a packet with three TCP flags : ACK, PSH, URG. This packet is dropped by the firewall between the client and the DB server and the connection is not established.

That is correct. The initial segment from the initiator ("client") to the listener ("server") needs to use the *SYN* flag. If successful, the listener replies with *SYN+ACK*. Then the initiator sends a final *ACK*, mutually synchronizing their respective *sequence number* values. This is the classic TCP 'three-way handshake'.

*PSH* and/or *URG* flags may be used with any subsequent data segments, with or without *ACK* - these segments may not be empty though (not just a pure ACK without sending data). Using those flags within the initial *SYN - SYN+ACK - ACK* handshake isn't legal accordingly. Using stateful inspection, a firewall may reject an empty segment with *PSH* or *URG*.

> Can a TCP data segment with a 1 byte length have, at the same time, the flags ACK, PSH, URG set ?

Yes. There's nothing in RFC 793 or common logic that prohibits such a segment, as long as it contains valid *acknowledgement number* and *urgent pointer* fields. You can check for yourself in [RFC 793](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793).

Comment: small note: every segment except the first one has an ACK flag set.